# Is these integral true or WA wrong?

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers

Playing with WA I have a trouble to understand something why we have (based on a numerical result from WA):
$$\int_0^e \operatorname{W}(x)^i\Big(-\operatorname{W}(x)\Big)^{-i} \, dx = \int_0^e \exp(x)^i(-\exp(x))^{-i}\,dx=\int_0^e \sin(x)^i(-\sin(x))^{-i} \, dx = e^{1+\pi}$$

Always with Wolfram alpha we have :

$$\int_0^e\tan(x)^i(-\tan(x))^{-i} \, dx = \int_0^e \cos(x)^i(-\cos(x))^{-i} \, dx = e^{1-\pi} + \pi\sinh(\pi)$$

### My question :

Is Wolfram alpha wrong or there exists a deeper formula ?

If it's good how to prove it ?

Maybe it's trivial I don't know I have not the skill to decide this .

Thanks a lot for share your knowledge .

Comment: What, actually, do $W(x)^i$ and $(-W(x))^{-i}$ mean?  Or more simply, what does $(-1)^i$ mean?

Comment: @kimchilover just speculating; maybe the OP is referring to the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) with $W$. OP needs to add details.

Comment: Why do you suspect this to be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that after simplification,

$$\int_0^e(-1)^{-i}dx=e\cdot(e^{i\pi})^{-i}=e^{1+\pi}.$$

For the other integrals, decompose the interval to handle the phase jumps.